# postcss - create custom properties in a loop

Tags: css, sass, postcss

I just moved from `SCSS` to `PostCSS` with `Webpack` and I'm wondering if it's possible to create custom properties dynamically.

A simple example:

```
/* input */
:root {
    @for $i from 1 to 3 {
        --layout-flex-$(i): {
            flex: $i;
        }
    }      
}

/* output */
:root {

    --layout-flex-1: {
        flex: 1;
    };

    --layout-flex-2: {
        flex: 2;
    };

    --layout-flex-3: {
        flex: 3;
    };
}
```

I searched for [`PreCSS`](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss), installed it and it works on simple `@for`, but with `--properties` I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 6d4f623…:606) at fn (bootstrap 6d4f623…:130) at Object.256 (index.css?e835:4) at Object. (bootstrap 6d4f623…:23) at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 6d4f623…:606) at fn (bootstrap 6d4f623…:130) at Object. (index.js:3) at Object. (client.js:2804) at Object.254 (client.js:2805) at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 6d4f623…:606)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-for

```
@for $i from 1 to 15 {
    --layout-flex-$(i): {
        flex: $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what i tried and have this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6d4f623…:606)
    at fn (bootstrap 6d4f623…:130)
    at Object.256 (index.css?e835:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap 6d4f623…:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6d4f623…:606)
    at fn (bootstrap 6d4f623…:130)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (client.js:2804)
    at Object.254 (client.js:2805)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6d4f623…:606)`

Comment: I'm sorry, my knowledge ends here, I never used wepback with boostrap and postcss... :(

Comment: Right. Thanks anyway